# Grub fails to boot my barebone Arch BTRFS setup

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, arch-linux, btrfs, grub2

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
I basically used the latest arch linux live disk in a VM (Linux KVM),

- booted the latest arch linux live disk in a VM (Linux KVM on Arch)
- made a single partition
- formatted that with btrfs -m dup
- mounted the partition, ran pacstrap with base and base-devel
- genfstab -U /mnt /mnt/etc/fstab
- arch-chroot into the partition at /mnt
- install grub through pacman, run grub-install /dev/vda and grub-mkconfig -o /etc/grub/grub.cfg
- reboot
- Grub throws a few error messages: "error: no such device: [some device ID].\n loading linux core repo kernel \n  error no such partition \n loading initial ramdisk \n error you need to load the kernel first \n  press any key to continue"

I can still boot the machine by going into the grub commandline, doing "linux (hd0,msdos1)/boot/vmlinuz...." and the same for initrd, and running "boot" to boot it, but that seems a little inconvenient.
Yes I'm cutting short some things like hostname and what not, but it *should* boot as far as I know.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I changed /etc/default/grub to not use UUIDs and ran grub-mkconfig again, here's the grub.cfg it generated: http://pastebin.ca/3746197
it still will not boot, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Not proud of my findings.

It's supposed to be grub-mkconfig -o **/boot**/grub/grub.cfg, not **/etc**/grub/grub.cfg. D'oh!

Leaving this here in case anyone else runs into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error with grub.

Try going into `/etc/default/grub` and turning off UUIDs, then running `grub-mkconfig` again.

Comment: I just tried this, but it doesn't change anything. in /etc/grub/grub.cfg I still see it using UUIDs... (I did run grub-mkconfig -o /etc ...)

Comment: I rebooted and ran it again, it seems to use UUIDs for some parts and /dev/vdaX format for others.. but it stil won't boot.

Comment: @Alex Hmm.. strange. What error is it giving you?

Comment: still the same "error no such device [rootfs UUID]" stuff

Comment: @Alex Shouldn't be giving UUID errors...

Try looking at your /etc/fstab and replacing the UUIDs there with `/dev/vd`whatever

Comment: No UUIDs in there either.. though it doesn't get that far, it fails loading the kernel/initramfs entirely, unless I manually specify their location in (hd0,msdos1)/boot/.... from the grub console